# Say there is an epimorphism $g$ from $G_1$ to $G_2$ , where $G_2$ is a cyclic group. Is $G_1$ also cyclic ? Prove or disprove.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, group-homomorphism

The converse holds   so if $G_1$ is cyclic it is shown that also $G_2$ is cyclic. I can not take the inverse of the function $g$ since the function is not injective ( i wanted to show that the generator of $G_2$ is mapped to the generator of $G_1$). Since the identity element of $G_2$ is mapped to $Kerg$ , then the generator of $G_2$ is mapped to one of the partitioned classes of $G_1$ and because of structure perserverance $G_1/Kerg$ isomorphic to $G_2$  and hence is cyclic.  From this point on I am stuck since I can not prove that if $G_1/Kerg$ is cyclic then $G$ is cyclic?
Thank you,

Comment: Do you mean homomorphism?  Epimorphism? Endomorphism is the wrong word here.

Comment: If all you mean is homomorphism, then no.  Just map all of $G_1$ to the identity.

Comment: I thought it might mean "injection", because at least that case would be interesting; homomorphism is bad as lulu points out; epimorphism is bad by mapping $S_3$ to $\Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z$. For an injection, I don't see quite such an obvious counterexample anywhere, but maybe I just need more caffeine.

Comment: If $f:G \to H$ is an injection, then $f(G)$ is a subgroup of $H$ and isomorphic to $G$. Since $H$ is cyclic, all subgroups are cyclic, and so $f(G) \cong G$ is cyclic.

Comment: Thank you for the replies , I meant epimirphism instead. I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: Thanks, @DKS: enlightenment is even better than a cup of coffee. :)

Comment: Happy to assist! 

Answer (score 3):

This is false. Map $S_n \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ ($n\geq 3$) using the sign of the permutation. The target is cyclic (and in fact, $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ for $n\geq 2$, just take $\langle (1,2) \rangle$ as the subgroup - just in case you need an endomorphism specifically), but the source is decidedly not.

To put in an edit quickly, if $f$ is an injection, then this is true. See my comment.

Comment: What do you mean by endomorphism? If you have an endomorphism and either domain or codomain is cyclic then the other is too by definition.

Comment: An endomorphism is a homomorphism from the algebraic object to itself. It need not be injective. The wording of the question matters, as the image could be cyclic.

Comment: How is that a counter example? The domain and codomain are still the same, hence cyclic simultaneously.

Comment: I misinterpreted you and edited my comment. It's due to ambiguity in the question. When the asker said endomorphism from $G_1$ to $G_2$, I assumed $G_2 < G_1$. So the image could be cyclic, while the total target space could be otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If by epimorphism of groups one understands a surjective homomorphism the the existence is sometimes possible, sometimes not. A counterexample has already been given in another answer. An example where it exists is given by $G_1 = C_{2m}$,   a cyclic group of order $2m$ and $G_2 = C_m$, a subgroup of $G_1$, the epimorphsm given by the projection  $g \mapsto g^2$.